# writing array to csv returns blank csv file

Tags: php

I have an array called $content with rows which has data like

```
$content[0]=name,title,city,country
$content[1]=name1,title1,city1,country1
```

How do I save this array as a `csv` file so that name is on column, title another and so on?

To write it to external file my code is

```
$file = fopen("d:/data.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
{
    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$content));
}

fclose($file);
```

but it has empty rows and columns.

Comment: `explode(',', $line)` ?

Comment: What is $list? And why are you running $content through explode?

Answer (score 0):

You've got your variables all mixed up. It should be:

```
foreach ($content as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, explode(',', $line));
}
```

But since `$line` is already a comma-separated string, you don't really need to explode it and use `fputcsv()`, you can just write it as it is.

```
file_put_contents("d:/data.csv", implode(PHP_EOL, $content) . PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is my example which i used you can get idea using this.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","a") or die("error");
    $res=mysqli_query($con, "select * from reg");
    $i = 0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $new[$i] =$row;
        $i++;
        }           
    function outputCSV($data) {
        $filename = "example";
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
        $outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');
        foreach($data as $val) {
            fputcsv($outputBuffer, $val);
        }
        fclose($outputBuffer);
    }    
    outputCSV($new);
```